# How to split a item in array to two item with conditional?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an example above.

Have array like:

```
array[0] = TODO 06:15PMJoin Michael
array[1] = WakeUp
array[2] = Going to schools
```

I want it become like:

```
array[0] = TODO 06:15PM
array[1] = Join Michael
array[2] = WakeUp
array[3] = Going to schools
```

In this example, I split item have content `TODO 06:15PMJoin Michael` to new two item.

Have two separate questions here:

How to create a role for creating a new item in an array?

I tried with my code:

`var splitList = words.SelectMany(x => x.Contains("AM") || x.Contains("PM"))`

But I don't know how to split from text `AM` or `PM` to the new item in `arrays`.

Comment: Maybe substring is easy to do this?

Comment: Using `SubString` when knowing exactly the length of the string you need a split.

In my case, `array` get values from IList<WebElement>. The values of array[0] is random. It only have `AM` or `PM` is role.

Comment: IndexOf can help you to find the index.

Comment: Thanks, @Kason. I don't think about `IndexOf` until your say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try finding `AM`/`PM` and get substrings:

```
  String[] array = new String[] {
    "TODO 06:15PMJoin Michael",
    "WakeUp",
    "Going to schools"
  };

  var result = array
    .SelectMany(line => {
        int p = line.IndexOf("AM");

        if (p >= 0)
          return new String[] { 
            line.Substring(0, p + "AM".Length), 
            line.Substring(p + "AM".Length) };

        p = line.IndexOf("PM");

        if (p >= 0)
          return new String[] { 
            line.Substring(0, p + "PM".Length), 
            line.Substring(p + "PM".Length) };

        return new String[] { line };
      }
    );
  //.ToArray(); // if you want to have array representation

  // Test
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: You awesome. Your answer resolve my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a problem with my array. My array is `word[6]` have 6 items. I want `words[0]` split new two item and add exist item.

`words = Regex.Split(words[0], @"\s{1,}").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();` but this code will delete exist item and create new arrays with 2 items.

Comment: @Văn Lộc: you on the right way, just use `SelectMany`: `words = words.SelectMany(item => Regex.Split(item, @"\s{1,}")).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
string[] array = new string[] {"TODO 06:15PMJoin Michael", 
    "WakeUp", 
    "Going to schools"};

string[] SplitArray(string[] array)
{
    List<string> returnArray = new List<string>();

    foreach (string item in array)
    {
        int index = GetIndex(item);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            string s1 = item.Substring(0, index + 2);
            string s2 = item.Substring(index + 2);
            returnArray.Add(s1);
            returnArray.Add(s2);
        }
        else
        {
            returnArray.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return returnArray.ToArray();
}

int GetIndex(string s)
{
    int index = GetIndexOf(s, "AM");

    if (index == -1)
    {
        index = GetIndexOf(s, "PM");
    }

    return index;
}

int GetIndexOf(string s, string delim)
{
    int index = -1;

    int tempIndex = 0;
    do
    {
        tempIndex = s.IndexOf(delim, tempIndex);
        if (tempIndex > 0)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(s[tempIndex-1]))
            {
                index = tempIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(tempIndex >= 0);

    return index;
}
```

Comment: I don't test your code. But seem you also answer right.